# To send value from codebehind to hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a property which has value i want to send the value to hidden field .pls help me to do this.

```
public string FieldLabel { get; set; }

 <asp:HiddenField ID="txthidd" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set the `value` as:

```
public string FieldLabel { 
     get{
        return txthidd.Value;
     } 

     set{
        txthidd.Value = value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind on page load:

```
txthidd.Value=FieldLabel ;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your codebehind page :-

> txthidd.Value = "Assigned Value";

Comment: how can i retrieve value from hidden field in another aspx page

Comment: u have to use java script for the same:-    

var HiddenValue = document.getElementById(thisRow + '_txthidd').value;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public string FieldLabel
{
    get { return txthidd.Value; }
    set { txthidd.Value = value; }
}
```

Then just set your property to set the hidden field value

```
FieldLabel = "new value";
```